# Embed a url in angular

Tags: angular, iframe, embed, facebook-iframe

I want to embed client-ui A in client-ui B. From local I am able embed client-ui A in B, but it fails on staging.

I do not see any error in console.
In the embed tag I see “client-ui A refused to connect.”

What could I be doing wrong? I am working in angular.

No url with https is being embedded, even if I try embedding google.com.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check your frame ancestors CSP (or x-frame-options, the older method): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors  I believe it will allow all local.  The browser will not allow framing/embedding content from a server that has this set.  (And it usually is for security reasons to prevent cross-site attacks)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be encountering issues with cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policies. In Angular, you may need to configure CORS settings on the server-side of client-ui A to allow embedding from client-ui B's domain. Check if CORS headers are properly configured on client-ui A's server. Additionally, ensure that both client-ui A and B are using HTTPS protocols, as some browsers enforce stricter security policies for embedding content from non-secure sources. If you're still facing issues, consider checking the network tab in your browser's developer tools for any specific error messages related to CORS.

Comment: Client-A api, is allowing all Origins. app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()); Embedded should work I guess. There is absolutely no error in console.